# Inserted column takes formatting from column to left?

Tags: excel, vba, formatting

I have a bunch of excel macros, and many of them involve inserting columns and putting calculation formulas in said columns. But I just realized now that when a new column is inserted it takes the formatting of the column to its left. So it may end up being formatted as text or something else, which is starting to negatively affect performance.

Is there a way to turn this default behavior off? is there a way I can do this in VBA without going through my code and putting `entireColumn.numberformat = "General` after EVERY time I insert new columns?

I know you can use the "PAste" options when pasting with right click, but what about VBA?

Comment: When you insert a column in Excel the "regular" way (i.e. without using a macro), doesn't it do the same thing?

Comment: Why not just do as you suggested and call `entireColumn.numberformat = "General"`.  What's wrong with that?

Comment: when doing it regular yes. But if you dont want that to happen you can use the paste options to select not to copy formatting or formulas etc.. and because i have many functions, and a good deal of them involve inserting columns so it'd take quite a while to go through all my code. If i'd known about this from the start it wouldnt be an issue but 4 months into development its kinda a problem XXDD

Answer (score 1):

There are two options when doing an insert:

Default:

```
Columns("D:D").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Columns("D:D").Insert Shift:=xlToRight ' CopyOrigin is default from Left or Above
```

second option:

```
Columns("D:D").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromRightOrBelow
```

If neither of these options work, you may consider having a column set up as you require, and insert it into the spreadsheet

```
Columns("BS:BS").Copy ' note that this should be on another sheet,
                      ' or tracked in some way, as it will move after
                      ' insert on same sheet
Columns("D:D").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
```